# Firefox and border-image with a linear gradient

Tags: css, firefox

Does Firefox actually support border-image with linear gradients? I keep seeing articles saying that it works but in my Firefox (v24) it actually doesn't show anything.

This example is using all the prefixes but it doesn't show any border at all in Firefox.

http://css-tricks.com/examples/GradientBorder/

Comment: According to the MDN it works with v29:  
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the page you link to indicates, Firefox doesn't support border gradients yet. I can't find much on it except [this article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image-source) which states that *"browser support is still limited"*, but from fiddling around with it, I can clearly see that it doesn't work. [This answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783061/proper-border-gradient-syntax-for-opera-and-firefox-i-have-the-webkit-syntax-wo#answer-7783169) shows a way to make some rudimentary gradients, but the syntax is cumbersome and the result is severely limited. You will probably have to use the *"Pseudo Element Edges"* from CSS-Tricks or wait until this part of CSS3 is completely standardised and implemented in Gecko.

Comment: You are right that the page indicates that it doesn't work in Firefox but since it's from 2011 I thought other browser would have caught up. I also saw that answer but went with using pseudo elements instead since that seems to work in IE10 as well.