# gradient border in firefox

Tags: css, firefox

im trying to create a gradient border in firefox with no luck, in chrome it displays perfectly with the following code:

```
#navigationBarContainer ul li {
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-family: optima;
    font-size:23px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top:8px;
    padding-bottom:8px;
    border-image: linear-gradient(0deg, transparent, #FFFFFF 50%, transparent) 1 0 100%;
    -webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, transparent, #FFFFFF 50%, transparent) 1 0 100%;
    -o-border-image: -o-linear-gradient(0deg, transparent, #FFFFFF 50%, transparent) 1 0 100%;
    -moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(0deg, transparent, #FFFFFF 50%, transparent) 1 0 100%;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
```

i have been trying with mozilla's border bottom property and certain variations but it doesnt seem to work:

```
  -moz-border-bottom-colors: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.8) 15%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 19%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 25%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 75%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 81%, rgba(255,255,255,0.8) 85%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
```

is there a correct way of acomplish this? without using images?

thanks in advance.

Comment: does it work if you remove the `-moz` line?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proper border gradient syntax for Opera and Firefox, I have the webkit syntax working fine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783061/proper-border-gradient-syntax-for-opera-and-firefox-i-have-the-webkit-syntax-wo)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, Firefox does not support gradients in border-images just now. Here is the [open bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=709587).

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do gradient borders for one site. Lucky for me it only had to be on 2 sides. The top border is solid and the side borders would fade out towards the bottom and there is no bottom border. This was what I did.

http://jsfiddle.net/aqBzd/1/

```
<div class = "box">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Body</p>
</div>

.box {
    background-color:orange;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-top:20px;
    width:200px;
    position:relative;
    border-top:3px solid red;
    padding:5px;
}

.box:before, .box:after {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,0,4,1) 0%, rgba(255,0,4,0) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,0,4,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,0,4,0)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,0,4,1) 0%,rgba(255,0,4,0) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,0,4,1) 0%,rgba(255,0,4,0) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,0,4,1) 0%,rgba(255,0,4,0) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,0,4,1) 0%,rgba(255,0,4,0) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff0004', endColorstr='#00ff0004',GradientType=0 );
    content:'';
    width:3px;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}

.box:before {
    left:0;
}

.box:after {
    right:0;
}
```

As far as I can tell this method only works for 2 borders, which may not work for you, but I figured I'd share my method anyways.